# Finding the product of two numbers in the same base system

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

> The sum of two three-digit numbers is 711 in a certain base system, which is not more than 10,and the second digit from the right of each number is zero. The difference between these numbers is 75 in the base system. What is the product of these two numbers in the same base system?

My understanding( what I know)

In base $10$ numbers included can be 0-9.

In base $9$ numbers included can be 0-8

In base $8$ numbers included can be 0-7.

There will be two equation

$A+B=711$

$A-B=75$

where $A$ and $B$ are two three digit numbers.

On addition in base $8$, I got $2A=1006$. Now $A=403$ in base $8$? How? I understood the addtion part

Comment: You should choose better titles for your questions. This question has the same title as [this other question of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388391/question-based-on-base-system-number-theory). You appear to have noticed the title problem by introducing a random space. You should also read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more.

Comment: Yes, you don't need to tell us it's a question; you need to summarize the problem. Title updated (and for the other one too).

Comment: Can you please explain @Joffan how on dividing we got 403 instead of 503?

Comment: Expressed in base 8, $2\times 4 =10$ and  $2\times 400 =1000$

Comment: Thankyou so much @Joffan

Comment: I got $144122_8=403_8\times 306_8$

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are $a0c$ and $d0f$ and the base is $B$ then

$$a0c\\ +d0f\\======\\ (a+d)0(c+f)\\===\\711$$

Okay, what does that *mean*?

You add $c+f$ and you get $1$.  If $c+f<B$ that means $c+f = 1$ and you go to the next column.  If $c + f \ge B$ then means $c+f = B+1$ and you carry the one to the next column.

We do the second column $0+0 =0\ne 1$ so ... that means we had to carry the one.

So $c +f = B+1$.

Then we do the third column $a+d =7$. That's that:  $c+f = B+1$ and $a+d =7$.

Now do the subtractionn

$$a0c\\ -d0f\\======\\ (a-d)0(c-f)\\===\\75$$

Okay, what does that *mean*?

We star with $c-f = 5$.  If $c\gef$ then $c-f=5$.  But if $c < f$ then we have to borrow from the next column, and we'd have $B+c-f = 5$.

The next column is $0-0=0 \ne 7$.  So that means we had to borrow.

So we have

$$a0c\\ -d0f\\======\\ (a-1)Bc\\-d0f\\=====\\(a-1)(B-1)(B+c)\\-d0f\\===\\75$$

And THAT means:

$B+c-f = 5$.  ANd $(B-1)-0 =7$ and $(a-1)-d =0$.

So.....

Can you  take it from there.